# mule dynamic insert data in json

Tags: mule

```
{
  "product1": {
     "addedBy": "1014",
    "addedDate": "1429681809598",
    "campaignName": promotion,
    "status": "Available"

  },
    "product2": {
       "addedBy": "1015",
      "addedDate": "1429681809598",
      "campaignName": bulkoffer,
      "status": "Available"

  },
    "product3": {
         "addedBy": "1015",
        "addedDate": "1429681809598",
        "campaignName": premiumoffer,
        "status": "Available"        
    }    
    }
```

in mule ,the above json is input data for me. I want to change the status value in runtime in mule. can anyone tell the way for it

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a map first:

```
<json:object-to-json-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" />
```

Then use MEL to update the map

```
<expression-component>payload.product1.status = 'Unavailable'</expression-component>
```

Then convert it back to json when you are ready:

```
<json:object-to-json-transformer />
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way is to use [Dataweave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation) which can fill your requirement easily and can change the value of `"status"` dynamically at runtime whichever `"status"`element you want to change

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
           %output application/json
           ---
           {
             product1: {
                 "addedBy": payload.product1.addedBy,
                 "addedDate": payload.product1.addedDate,
                 "campaignName": payload.product1.campaignName,
                 "status": "Unavailable" 
            },
             product2:{
                 "addedBy": payload.product2.addedBy,
                 "addedDate": payload.product2.addedDate,
                 "campaignName": payload.product2.campaignName,
                 "status": "Unavailable" 
           },
             product3:{
                 "addedBy": payload.product3.addedBy,
                 "addedDate": payload.product3.addedDate,
                 "campaignName": payload.product3.campaignName,
                 "status": "Unavailable" 
           }

           } ]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
```